Is there a proper way to run a GitHub Action pull_request event when there are conflicts with the base branch?
There's this unanswered GitHub communities discussion about GitHub Actions pull_request events not being triggered when there are conflicts with the base branch set in the PR.
The GitHub Actions team hasn't suggested a real solution to this issue for more than 5 years now.
I have GitHub Action that creates a Docker image and pushes it to an ECR repository.
This is the scenario when the issue occurs:
             I--J   <-- feature/first_branch (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H--Z   <-- master


Commits J and Z are conflicted, and now the pull_request event in my GitHub Action won't be triggered since there's a conflict.
I know that push events don't have this issue, but I must use a pull_request event because I need to know what's the current branch's base branch because I cache-from the base branch's latest image.
I have a hack that works for me - I create another branch (feature/second_branch) that's based on feature/first_branch. Then I make a random commit that has no meaning so there'll be a diff between feature/second_branch and feature/first_branch (as GitHub doesn't allow opening PRs when there's no diff between the 2 branches you compare).
                  K--M   <-- feature/second_branch (HEAD)
                 /
             I--J   <-- feature/first_branch
            /
...--F--G--H--Z   <-- master


Once I open a PR where feature/first_branch is the base - I manage to trigger a pull_request event have a branch with the code I want and isn't conflicted with its base branch.
That way there're no conflicts between them and I get my Docker image.
The problem with this hack is that I have no image to cache-from when feature/first_branch has no latest image pushed to the ECR (which is basically similar to triggering a push event in first place).
This issue doesn't happen on CircleCI flows, but I can't migrate this flow from GitHub Actions at the moment.
Is there a way to overcome this issue without any hacks, or at least a simpler hack than mine?

What's preventing people from actually solving the mere conflict? cause that's the simplest way from solving the issue.

@jessehouwing We have a limitation in our SDLC that requires us to maintain old stable versions called "validated versions". We can't rebase those "valid" type branches because it isn't permitted to do so.
That's a problem because whenever there's an urgent hotfix to merge to a "valid" branch the pull_request event won't trigger and a new Docker image won't be generated. This prevents us from deploying an image unless someone performs this hack I mentioned to generate an image.

You won't need to rebase the branch, but you do need to resolve the merge conflicts. Reverse integrating the target branch would fix the merge issue. The PR trigger would result in checking out a conflict state. So either you'll need te use the push trigger, as you already mentioned, or push a commit that resolves the merge conflicts to the branch you are merging from.

@jessehouwing Reverse integration is basically the same as rebasing, isn't it? Anyway, you're right about having to use push events in this case. I still find it odd that merge conflicts prevent CI from running... I wonder if there's a reason why the GitHub Actions team don't just remove this constraint.

CI cannot run on a pull request when there is a conflict, because the CI workflows runs on a temporary merge commit, not on the head of the PR. When there is a conflict, that merge conflict cannot be automatically created, and so the state the CI is meant to run on just doesn't exist. It's not an arbitrary constraint, it's a fundamental impossibility, unless you actually change the definition of what the pull request event does.

@RoyGal, no reverse integration isn't the same as rebasing. Reverse integration is merging the changes from master back into feature/x. This will create a new merge  commit K, which merges Z into feature/x.

@joanis Cool! I didn't know that. If I knew it's by design I wouldn't be as upset as I was. What's the source for this information?

@jessehouwing I understand but that doesn't change the fact that the commits are conflicted. The 2 main differences between rebase and reverse integration in this case is how the git log would look like and my commit SHAs.

@RoyGal I know this primarily by experience, but https://docs.github.com/en/actions/writing-workflows/choosing-when-your-workflow-runs/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request has relevant information, including what ref the workflow runs on, which is (somewhat obscurely, imho) saying the same thing: "Note that GITHUB_SHA for this event is the last merge commit of the pull request merge branch." The "pull request merge branch" is a branch that is not visible by default that contains the result of merging the PR, which I was describing above as a "temporary merge commit".

@RoyGal aReverse integrayion is fixing the merge conflicts. This will allow the pull request trigger to run as normal.

@jessehouwing Rebasing forces you to fix the merge conflicts too. I still don't see how does reverse integration differ from a rebase in this case.

Rebase would rewrite history and push new versions of I and J with Z as a base. Reverse integration will create a new commit after I and J which solves the merge commit. Especially when collaborating with multiple developers, reverse integration will cause fewer issues, but a slightly less clean history. Since the branch has been pushed to the remote, it's generally not advised to rebase. If this only existed locally, I'd rebate.

@jessehouwing Alright, let's wrap this up. I agree that branches worked on by multiple developers shouldn't be rebased under any circumstances. While both rebasing and reverse integrating the branch would achieve the same result I want (resolving the merge conflicts), I can't do either because 'valid' branches in our process are not allowed to incorporate any new code from their base branch (e.g., master) once they are created. Introducing new changes would violate our SDLC requirements. Thanks for your responses and patience.
